# Icons in Dash show up in weird colors. OpenGL Issue?

Tags: unity-dash, colors, intel-hd

I have a somewhat weird issue with my Precise setup (32bit). Since last Friday some colors are very different from the original ones. But only in the Dash (not in Nautilus or the panel). Moreover, the Gameboy-Advance emulator VBA-M also got blue, when OpenGL-rendering is chosen instead of Cairo.

My graphics chipset is an Intel HD 3000.

I tried to erase all unity-related config data and using the original icons, but they are also colored. When using a guest-account, those icons appear orange (I once changed the color-scheme to blue). In fact, it looks a bit inverted but I'm not sure.

I also reinstalled the graphics driver, nothing changed.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/KHfu1.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/x5DLK.png]

Comment: Is there any possibility to reset those icons/thumbnails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed 13.04 over the old OS and the problem disappeared (but I kept the configuration files in /home). Seems to be a graphics drivers issue.